# Ionic 4 component library ion-radio css customisation

Tags: ionic4

I have a question regarding the ion-radio component from the Ionic 4 component library.
Unfortunately this component https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio allows very little access to customise it's CSS through CSS variables. What i'm trying to achieve is to set the style of this checkbox icon to match this https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQnkY.png . Currently the style is the default one which corresponds to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm9UQ.png. I've tried targeting the inner classes to no avail. I think it's because the divs are rendered inside the shadow-dom of the component ion-radio itself.I know this could be done with javascript, i would rather keep this as a last resort. Does anyone know of any other solution of achieving the same styling using this component?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is Ionic issue [#20140](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/20140) that will introduce new variable properties --border-radius and --inner-border-radius to the ion-radio component. The PR has been accepted is included in [5.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases).

Although the inner border radius is set to 50% if you're not using 5.0.0-beta.3 or  higher, you can still change the CSS to address some of your needs. Maybe something like this?

```
ion-radio {
    --color-checked:green;
    --color:green;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with CSS to achieve this. Hide the `ion-radio`:

```css
ion-radio {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Place your custom radio button/shape inside `ion-item`:

```html
<ion-radio-group>
  <ion-item>
     <ion-radio slot="start" value="foo" checked></ion-radio>
     <ion-icon slot="start" mode="ios" name="radio-button-off" />
     <ion-label>foo</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
     <ion-radio slot="start" value="bar" checked></ion-radio>
     <ion-icon slot="start" mode="ios" name="radio-button-off" />
     <ion-label>bar</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>
```

Use the Ionic `.item-radio-checked` class:

```css
ion-radio-group .item-radio-checked ion-icon {
  fill: teal;
}

ion-radio-group ion-icon::after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.28s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

ion-radio-group .item-radio-checked ion-icon::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

This works for `md` mode only, but you can customize it further for `ios` with CSS.